# add to cart message is displaying in other pages , but button is present in my account page

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

**Edit**

Once we click on "ADD TO CART" in "My account" page and if we open any other pages like home page , catalog page, product page, i can see message there, but not displaying in My account page.

**Edit end**

In "My designs" section, Under **My account** we are displaying some products and gave an option for "Add to cart" and its working fine.

[image]

now i need to display **message** on top of the page after customer click on "Add to cart" similar to [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/a-mark-of-the-danger-warning-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) :

[image]

For "Add to cart" button, i am trying same code that we are using in product view page, but its not displaying any message.

app/design/frontend/rwd/Stylebaby/template/example/example.phtml

```
<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>

<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {

    echo $product->getName().' <br>';
?>
<form action="<?php echo  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);?>" method="post">  
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">

<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" >
    <span><span>
    <?php echo $buttonTitle ?>
    </span></span>
</button>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

</div>
</form>
<hr style='display:inline-block; width:100%;'>
<?php 

}
?>
```

**Edit**

app/code/local/Amasty/Example/controllers/mydesigncontrollers.php  - http://pastebin.com/rpjjMthf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add messages on your page, you need to add Layout Message block on your controller. Here in your case, 
**app/code/local/Amasty/Example/controllers/MyDesignController.php**

```
public function indexAction() {
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
    }
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

And get Groped Html on top in your phtml,
**app/design/frontend/rwd/Stylebaby/template/example/example.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
```

or

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

add below code into your controller **after load Layout**

```
$this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried your code as here, but it didt worked for me, what wrong i am doing here : http://pastebin.com/FjiUx2tr

Comment: I edited question, when you get free time, please look once.....

Comment: after adding product to cart on which page it is redirecting? @BabyinMagento

Comment: it staying in same page, but not displaying any message in same page, but when i opened any other pages, its displaying message there.....

Comment: you are using Ajax ? @BabyinMagento

Comment: no normal `add to cart` only

Comment: try updated answer @BabyinMagento

Comment: we have this code  : `->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')` in  `function indexAction()`  , i added your code as : `addtocart` : http://pastebin.com/AMudN9d4

`cartControler.php` : http://pastebin.com/NfqB3RMc  i am getting : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in   line `$this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')`

Comment: provide your controller @BabyinMagento

Comment: this is complete code, please check http://pasted.co/17de7a33

Comment: try to add my code in `\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php` `indexAction()` just for test if works that override that controller

Comment: sorry, it didt worked for me, Thanks a lot for your support, i got solution....

Comment: Ok Amasty has override the controller thats why my solution is not working @BabyinMagento

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right, i am extremely sorry that i didt informed that one to you before..... Need your support like same in upcoming days also......